# Compose Multiplatform JS compilation issue : java.lang.AssertionError: Assertion failed

Tags: javascript, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

Currently I am working on a Compose multiplatform project and facing issue in compiling **Web platform**. Following is the stacktrace that is printed while compiling the code.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Assertion failed
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.JsAstUtilsKt.checkOnNullability(jsAstUtils.kt:430)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.JsAstUtilsKt.translateCallArguments(jsAstUtils.kt:401)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.JsAstUtilsKt.translateCallArguments$default(jsAstUtils.kt:385)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.JsAstUtilsKt.translateCall(jsAstUtils.kt:163)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrElementToJsExpressionTransformer.visitCall(IrElementToJsExpressionTransformer.kt:235)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrElementToJsExpressionTransformer.visitCall(IrElementToJsExpressionTransformer.kt:25)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrCall.accept(IrCall.kt:26)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrElementToJsStatementTransformer$maybeOptimizeIntoSwitch$2.invoke(IrElementToJsStatementTransformer.kt:114)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrElementToJsStatementTransformer$maybeOptimizeIntoSwitch$2.invoke(IrElementToJsStatementTransformer.kt:114)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrElementToJsStatementTransformer$visitReturn$lastStatementTransformer$2.invoke(IrElementToJsStatementTransformer.kt:142)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrElementToJsStatementTransformer$visitReturn$lastStatementTransformer$2.invoke(IrElementToJsStatementTransformer.kt:131)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrElementToJsStatementTransformer.maybeOptimizeIntoSwitch(IrElementToJsStatementTransformer.kt:114)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrElementToJsStatementTransformer.visitReturn(IrElementToJsStatementTransformer.kt:146)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrElementToJsStatementTransformer.visitReturn(IrElementToJsStatementTransformer.kt:32)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrReturn.accept(IrReturn.kt:26)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrElementToJsStatementTransformer.visitBlockBody(IrElementToJsStatementTransformer.kt:40)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrElementToJsStatementTransformer.visitBlockBody(IrElementToJsStatementTransformer.kt:32)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBlockBody.accept(IrBlockBody.kt:25)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.JsAstUtilsKt.translateFunction(jsAstUtils.kt:118)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrFunctionToJsTransformer.visitSimpleFunction(IrFunctionToJsTransformer.kt:30)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrFunctionToJsTransformer.visitSimpleFunction(IrFunctionToJsTransformer.kt:16)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrSimpleFunction.accept(IrSimpleFunction.kt:37)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.JsClassGenerator.generateMemberFunction(JsClassGenerator.kt:318)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.JsClassGenerator.generateClassBlock(JsClassGenerator.kt:129)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.JsClassGenerator.generate(JsClassGenerator.kt:64)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrDeclarationToJsTransformer.visitClass(IrDeclarationToJsTransformer.kt:30)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrDeclarationToJsTransformer.visitClass(IrDeclarationToJsTransformer.kt:13)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.accept(IrClass.kt:73)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrFileToJsTransformer.visitFile(IrFileToJsTransformer.kt:25)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrFileToJsTransformer.visitFile(IrFileToJsTransformer.kt:14)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrFile.accept(IrFile.kt:31)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrModuleToJsTransformer.generateProgramFragment(IrModuleToJsTransformer.kt:355)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrModuleToJsTransformer.access$generateProgramFragment(IrModuleToJsTransformer.kt:126)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrModuleToJsTransformer$makeIrFragmentsGenerators$2$1.invoke(IrModuleToJsTransformer.kt:221)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.transformers.irToJs.IrModuleToJsTransformer$makeIrFragmentsGenerators$2$1.invoke(IrModuleToJsTransformer.kt:221)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.ic.CacheUpdater.generateIrFragments(CacheUpdater.kt:759)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.ic.CacheUpdater.actualizeCaches(CacheUpdater.kt:770)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.js.K2JsIrCompiler.prepareIcCaches(K2JsIrCompiler.kt:615)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.js.K2JsIrCompiler.doExecute(K2JsIrCompiler.kt:253)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.js.K2JSCompiler.doExecute(K2JSCompiler.java:181)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.js.K2JSCompiler.doExecute(K2JSCompiler.java:72)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:104)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:48)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
```

Note : Android, iOS and desktop apps are working perfectly

Comment: `ir.backend` means the issue is in Kotlin compiler, try making a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and report it to [youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues)

Comment: looks like a null value being flagged and throwing an error. If you're compiling JS code from TS, If I were trouble shooting this, I'd want to track what is being passed in on line 430 of the jsAstUtils.kt and step through that.